# PHP MySQL Nested Lists for Customer Data

Tags: php, mysql, html-lists

I have a nested list that will show customers and their phone numbers like this:

**Jason**

```
555 111-1111
555 222-2222
```

**Kristen**

```
555 333-3333
```

**John**

```
555 444-4444
555 555-5555
555 656-6666
```

I'm having trouble adding their emails, though. This code just duplicates the email under each phone number, but I need the phone numbers and emails to be grouped under each customer like:

**Jason**

```
555 111-1111
555 222-2222
jason@jason.com
jason.alternative@jason.com
```

**Kristen**

```
555 333-3333
kristen@kristen.com
kristen.alternative@kristen.com
kristen.personal@kristen.com
```

**John**

```
555 444-4444
555 555-5555
555 656-6666
john@john.com
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,"
SELECT 
fname, 
phone, 
email
FROM 
customer, 
phone, 
email, 
customer_phone, 
customer_email
WHERE
customer.id=customer_phone.customer_id
AND
phone.id=customer_phone.phone_id
AND
customer.id=customer_email.customer_id
AND
email.id=customer_email.email_id
order by fname
");

$oldname = null;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($oldname != $row['fname'])
    {
        echo "<h3>".$row['fname']."</h3>";
        $oldname = $row['fname'];
    }
    echo "<p>".$row['phone']."</p>";
    echo "<p>".$row['email']."</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi what's the schema of your tables? Is it duplicating the same email for each user right now even if they have multiple emails stored? What's your current output.

Comment: What's the difference between phone and customer phone | email and customer email?

Comment: Sorry, customer_phone and customer_email are junction tables. Yes, it is duplicating the same email and not displaying all the emails for each customer.

Comment: Is it showing the correct phone numbers?

Comment: Yes, the phone number and emails are correct.

Comment: Why don't you simplify your tables? User table -> id, name .. email table -> id, userId, email .. phone table -> id, userId, email. That way you don't need 5 tables, just 3. Also, when you call SELECT * FROM email where userId = 1 you get all emails belonging to user 1.

Comment: Btw a junction table would be good IF the relation is many to many. But in your case, because the email and phone is unique the relation is just one to many. It allows you to simplify it a little.

Comment: Would that still allow many-to-many relationships? My application will need to allow customers to have multiple phone numbers and emails, but also let customers share phone numbers and emails.

Comment: Oh I presumed a little there. It won't actually.

Answer (score 1):

This query will slot the emails in after the phone numbers, by getting the phone numbers first and the emails second. The column with '1-Phone' and '2-Email' makes sure the emails sort after the phone numbers.

```
SELECT fname, '1-Phone' AS InfoType, phone AS TheInfo
  FROM Customer
  INNER JOIN phone ON phone.id=customer_phone.phone_id
  INNER JOIN customer_phone ON customer.id=customer_phone.customer_id
UNION SELECT fname, '2-Email', email
  FROM Customer
  INNER JOIN email ON email.id=customer_email.email_id
  INNER JOIN customer_email ON customer.id=customer_email.customer_id
ORDER BY fname, InfoType
```

I changed the joins to ANSI syntax because it made it easier for me to work on this; no other reason. Feel free to push the join conditions back to the `WHERE` clause if that's your preference - I don't feel strongly about it :)

The only change to the rendering code is to replace this...

```
echo "<p>".$row['phone']."</p>";
echo "<p>".$row['email']."</p>";
```

... with this:

```
echo "<p>".$row['TheInfo']."</p>";
```

Comment: Thanks, but yeah, the JOIN and UNION stuff confuses me still. I just recently wrapped my head around the SELECT query for this, so I was hoping to build on that for now.

Comment: I understand. The JOIN syntax was hard for me at first but it was the standard for a gig I had years ago. I came to prefer it because it separates the join logic from the filter logic; it's hard to go back :). As for UNION, the first SELECT just gets a bunch of rows, then each successive one just appends more rows. There's a tiny bit more to it, but that's the basics.

Comment: Cool. Thanks, Grace. I'm going to look more into that and study your example.